# What kind of Sage mode does Kabuto have?

Tags: naruto

Is it a Dragon sage or Snake? I thought it was Snake until I read this:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Snake.

> Sage Mode can be learned in two places, Mount Myōboku of the toads and [Ryūchi Cave](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ry%C5%ABchi_Cave) of the [snakes](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Snakes). Learning Sage Mode at Mount Myōboku or Ryūchi Cave grants the user with a toad and snake style of Sage

Source: [Sage Mode - Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sage_Mode)

[image: Kabuto in Sage Mode]

> After Orochimaru's sealing, Kabuto travelled across the world and ultimately discovered the location of the Ryūchi Cave. There, he was taught senjutsu by the White Snake Sage and gained access to Sage Mode. Physically, Kabuto undergoes little alteration in this form, with the only visible changes being the markings around his eyes extending onto his back and the growth of four horns on the back of his head, as well as darkened sclerae.
>
> [...] Kabuto also gains access to further snake anatomy, such as their brille, which allows him to severely impair his opponents through the use of intense light whilst remaining completely unaffected himself. [...]
>
> Due to his research and self-modifications based on Jūgo's clan's abilities, Kabuto's body can passively and continuously absorb natural energy without aid even when moving, allowing him to potentially maintain his Sage Mode indefinitely. According to Kabuto, this meant that he was no longer a snake, **but had instead transcended into a dragon**

Source: [Kabuto Yakushi - Narutopedia](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kabuto_Yakushi) (emphasis added)

Comment: ohh.. for a moment i thought he really became Dragon sage. Thanks! :)

Comment: A little bit of correction: Sage Mode can be learned *at least* in two places. There may be other places too (as there are other types of summons) we just don't know about them. (Of course I'm not saying that it makes Kabuto a dragon.)

Comment: How are the summoned beasts related to sage mode? I mean does every summoned beast come from a place where their respective sage mode can be learned??